# Setup SSL on Discourse deployed in Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, discourse

I just finished setting up a discourse community in Amazon using the default installer (not Docker nor Discourse-Bitnami from Amazon). And now I wanted to set up SSL to enable https access. I've created the domain's certificate using Amazon Certificate. However, all the online instructions use 3rd party certificates.

*Note: I have tried the load balancer approach too similar to WordPress, but it doesn't work (http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com/2018/07/enable-https-on-wordpress-in-amazon.html).

Is it possible to enable SSL on Discourse deployed on Amazon using Amazon Certificate with or without using a Load Balancer?

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the discourse docs the recommended approach would be to use nginx as a load balancer (would connect your discourse application to the incoming traffic and enable https) [how to setup nginx with a commercial certificate authority](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority#install-certificate-on-web-server)

- [discourse documentation for setting up docker and standalone](https://meta.discourse.org/t/advanced-setup-only-allowing-ssl-https-for-your-discourse-docker-setup/13847)
- [how to install nginx on ubuntu 14.04-lts](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) (note: you might need to install using yum instead of apt-get)

Comment: As much as possible I would like to use Amazon's own load balancer to lessen the work.